# Baby Rudin theorem 11.42

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, cauchy-sequences

There are the definitions which we need for the proof of the theorem :
[image]

[image]

There is the theorem:
If ${f_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathscr L^2(\mu)$ , then there exists a function $f$ $\in$ $\mathscr L^2(\mu)$  such that ${f_n}$ converges to $f$ in $\mathscr L^2(\mu)$ .

This says, in other words, that $\mathscr L^2(\mu)$  is a complete metric space.

There is the proof:

since ${f_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, we can find a sequence ${n_k}$, $k$ $=$ $1,2,3,...,$ such that

$||f_{nk}-f_{n{k+1}}||$  $\lt$  $\frac {1}{2^k}$. ($k$ $=$ $1,2,3,...,$).

Choose a function $g$ $\in$  $\mathscr L^2(\mu)$ .  By the Schwarz inequality,

$\int_{X} |g(f_{nk}-f_{n{k+1}})| d\mu $ $\leq$ $\frac {||g||}{2^k}$ .

Hence

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty $ $\int_{X} |g(f_{nk}-f_{n{k+1}})| d\mu $ $\leq$ $||g||$.

I couldn't understand How do we get the first inequality by the Schwarz inequality, and thereby, I also  couldn't understand how do we get the last inequality ( $\sum_{k=1}^\infty $ $\int_{X} |g(f_{nk}-f_{n{k+1}})| d\mu $ $\leq$ $||g||$.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Application of C-S is straightforward . For your second question just  note that $\sum \frac  1 {2^{k}}=1$.

Comment: Be careful, $\|\cdot\|$ is not a norm on $\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ as we may have $\|f\| = 0$ with $f\neq 0$ (just take a function that vanishes almost everywhere).

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks for the second question. can you answer on the 1st question more explicitly?

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives $\int |uv|\,d\mu\le \left (\int |u|^2\,d\mu\right )^{1/2} \left (\int |v|^2\,d\mu\right )^{1/2}=\|u\|\,\|v\|.$ In your case $u=g$ and $v=f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k+1}}.$